# Modular Inverse of a number

Tags: algorithm, modular-arithmetic

Recently I have read extended euclid's algorithm which is used to find out the modular inverse of a number `N` whith respect to `MOD` such that `gcd(N,MOD)=1`.

But I have a doubt about how to find modular inverse of a number if `gcd(N,MOD)!=1`?

Comment: Sorry c++ is added by mistake

Comment: In this case, `N` simply doesn't have an inverse.

Answer (score 2):

If `gcd(N,MOD)!=1` a modular inverse of N does not exist.

However, in some cases you can still divide by N, i.e. find an X such that A = N * X (mod MOD). This is possible when gcd(N,MOD) divides gcd(A,MOD). To find such an X just divide A, N, and MOD by gcd(N,MOD) and then proceed as normally (gcd(N', MOD') is then 1).